# Android SQLite delete user failed

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, crud

I'm now currently working on android application with login function, I want to make it so people can delete their own account. I tried some code but it failed to delete.
Here's code for my delete method... I declared this method on LoginDataBaseAdapater Class.

```
    public boolean deleteUser(String Username)
    {String user=String.valueOf(Username);
    return db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, KEY_USER +"=" + user, null) > 0;}
```

Then I need to call it in activity, I don't know which part of my activity is wrong... Since the code is very long, I try to shortened it like this...

```
package shiro.yuki; 
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class menulayanan extends ListActivity {
 LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
 LoginDataBaseAdapter db;
 User user;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    final LoginDataBaseAdapter db = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String uname = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("username");
    final User user = db.getUserDetail(uname);


    String[] menulayanan = new String[] {"A","B"};
    setListAdapter(new array(this, menulayanan));

}

    public void detail() {
        db.deleteUser2(user.getUser()); // from logcat seems that this code is wrong

        Toast.makeText(menulayanan.this, "Hapus Sukses !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String pilihan = o.toString();
    tampilkanPilihan(pilihan);
}
public void tampilkanPilihan(String pilihan) {
    try {
        //Intent digunakan untuk sebagai pengenal suatu activity
        Intent i = null;
        if (pilihan.equals("A")) {
            i = new Intent(this, A.class);
                } else if (pilihan.equals("B")) {
            i = new Intent(this, B.class);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Anda Memilih: " + pilihan + " , Actionnya belum dibuat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.opt_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder3.setMessage("Ingin menghapus account ?")
            .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ya",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    detail(); // from logcat seems that this code is wrong too
                    keluar();
                }   
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Tidak",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}


public void keluar() {
    Intent awal = new Intent (this, Doa.class);
    startActivity(awal);
    finish();
}

public void belajar(){
    Intent Pembelajaran = new Intent (this, Pembelajaran.class);
    startActivity(A);   

}
}
```

And from code above, there's a method called getUserDetail, I declared this method in LoginDataBaseAdapter Class too, I kinda think that with this method, I can catch username from who's the active user now. Here's the code..

```
    public User getUserDetail(String Username)
    {
    User user = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.query("login", new String[]{"Username", "Password"}, 
    "Username='" +Username+ "'", null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
    user = new User();
    user.setUser(cursor.getString(0));
    user.setPass(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    {
    cursor.close();
    }
    return user;
    }
```

User class itself is just class with some method of getUser,getPassword,setUser and setPassword

Please help.....

Comment: You should post the class where is defined `deleteUser`. Do you have any error logs in logcat?

Comment: @YoannHercouet
Yes, I'm sorry... I already include comment of which part of my code that error from logcat here's the logcat 


`05-30 14:07:13.902: E/AndroidRuntime(724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`
`05-30 14:07:13.902: E/AndroidRuntime(724): java.lang.NullPointerException `
`05-30 14:07:13.902: E/AndroidRuntime(724): at shiro.yuki.menulayanan.detail(menulayanan.java:47)`
` 05-30 14:07:13.902: E/AndroidRuntime(724): at shiro.yuki.menulayanan$5.onClick(menulayanan.java:147)` 

and here's the class where I declared getUserDetail

http://tny.cz/e47b904b

Comment: You should debug your application, the problem is not your delete function but I guess this variable: `user.getUser()` that is null.

Comment: @YoannHercouet is it that it failed to catch value of username ?? 
but i think I already try to catch it from method getUserDetail,

So I debug it too... and like you said it seems like
`db.deleteLagi(user.getUser());`
was wrong and cause null...
But I have no idea how to fix it... I mean, how do I catch username from here ???